# ng-repeat on table cell instead of row

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to use ng-repeat on cell instead of row? and I know I said "table" in the title, but I want to avoid using table if possible.

I have a `collection` of `item`, and I want to display the `items` one after another, and their position depends on the number of item per row allowed.

For example, I have 7 `items` in the `collection`.

If I specify 3 items per row, my result should look like this.

[image: Example 1]

If I specify 4 items per row, my result should look like this.

[image: Example 2]

Is there a way to use one `ng-repeat` to achieve this? I'm expecting the result to be something like this:

```
<div> <!--ng-repeat here-->
    <span>item1</span>
    <span>item2</span>
    <span>item3</span>
    <br>
    <span>item4</span>
    <span>item5</span>
    <span>item6</span>
    <br>
    <span>item7</span>
    <span>item8</span>
</div>
```

Or am I forced to us nested `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you can try something simple, like:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
  <div style="width: 33%; height: 100px; float: left">{{i}}</div>
</div>
```

Second, you can manually group items in controller to 2-dim array:

```
<div ng-repeat="iRow in groupedItems">
  <div ng-repeat="i in iRow">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left">{{i}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Third, you can write directive to group items for you, and that can look like:

```
   <div group-items="items" group-items-per-row="4" group-items-result="groupedItems" group-items-regroup="yourTrigger">
    <div ng-repeat="iRow in groupedItems">
      <div ng-repeat="i in iRow">
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left">{{i}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a <div> container wrapping around all the items. I noticed when I use 'float: left' the container doesn't grow with the list of items. Is there a way to go about it?

Answer (score 3):

The html structure you want to create can done using `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` directives. For example:

JS

```
var app = angular.module('testapp', []);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
  $scope.itemsPerRow = 3;
});
```

HTML:

```
  <body ng-app="testapp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
      Number of item per row: <input type="number" ng-model="itemsPerRow" />
      <br />
      <span ng-repeat-start="item in items">{{item}}</span>
      <br ng-repeat-end="" ng-if="$index!=0 && ($index+1)%itemsPerRow==0"/>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here is the plunker that demonstrates this: http://plnkr.co/edit/bDfRAbMVoOlwNW2iQkso?p=preview